# Django path to settings file

Tags: python, django, settings

I am trying to create custom Django template. The structure of the project template is as follows:

```
project_name/
  docs/
  reqs/
  src/
    ...
    settings/
      ...
      dev.py
      prod.py
    manage.py
    wsgi.py
    ...
  Procfile
  requirements.txt
```

I am having trouble figuring out the right way to include the settings file at `manage.py` and `wsgi.py`. Should it be `src.settings.dev` or `settings.dev`?

At present,

`manage.py` has `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings.dev")` (at localhost)

and

`wsgi.py` has `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODLE", "src.settings.prod")`. (at heroku)

Both of which works fine with commands `./manage.py runserver` and `gunicorn src.wsgi` respectively.

I wish to know what determines the path to settings. Is it the file being executed or the project path? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to know that when settings file is supplied to manage.py, it tries to find the settings at two places,
    1. At the path relative to it (manage.py)
    2. and at PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it has nothing to do with either of these. The settings file is a normal Python module, and so it must be able to be imported like any other Python module - which means that the base of the path must be on the PYTHONPATH.

In your case, something is probably adding both "/path/to/project_name" and "/path/to/project_name/src" to the PYTHONPATH, either by settting the environment variable, or by directly modifying `sys.path` inside the script.

Comment: I haven't placed either of the path in PYTHONPATH and environment variable.